# How do I remove ending "/" from URL path in a Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, xml-rpc

I want to map my RPC service to **http://path.com/RPC2** rather than /RPC2/

Inside my web.xml file, I currently have the url-pattern set to **/**

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RPC2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried to merely remove the url-pattern, but this didn't work. When I remove the url-pattern entry, Tomcat won't deploy it and Jetty works but at ../RPC2/

Here's the full XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <description>Automatos RPC Server</description>
        <servlet-name>RPC2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>RPCServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>streamMessages</param-name>
            <param-value>1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <!-- Optional! Defaults to text/xml and ISO-8859-1 -->
            <param-name>contentType</param-name>
            <param-value>text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RPC2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy your webapp on context root (in Tomcat, just rename the WAR to `ROOT.war` or set `<Context path="">` instead of `<Context path="/RPC2">`). This way your webapp will be deployed to http://path.com. This way you can map the servlet on an URL pattern of `/RPC2` and the servletcontainer won't auto-redirect to the webapp root `/` anymore.